# zoo_aget_children() keeper calling the callback function

Tags: c++, linux, apache-zookeeper

## Description:

I use `zoo_aget_children(handle, node, 0, callback, context)` to set a watch for node. And then, in the `callback`:

```
zhandle_t *_handle = NULL;
const char *path = "/downloader_service";

void init_callback(zhandle_t *handle, int type, int state, const char *path, void *context) {
    if (type == ZOO_SESSION_EVENT) {
        if (state == ZOO_CONNECTED_STATE)
            cout<<"zookeeper connected"<<endl;
    }
}

void callback(int rc, const struct String_vector *strings, const void *data) {
    if (rc != ZOK)
        cerr<<"callback: "<<zerror(rc)<<endl;
    cerr<<"callback called."<<endl;
    zoo_aget_children(_handle, path, 1, callback, data);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    zoo_set_debug_level(ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR);
    _handle = zookeeper_init("127.0.0.1:2181", init_callback, 30000, 0, 0, 0);
    if (_handle == NULL)
        zerror(errno);

    sleep(1); // let zookeeper connect first
    int rc = zoo_aget_children(_handle, path, 1, callback, (void *)path);
    if (rc != ZOK)
        cerr<<"main: "<<zerror(rc)<<endl;

    while (1)
        sleep(86400);

    return 0;
}
```

Zookeeper continue calling `callback` even if the children of `node` haven't changed. Zookeeper version `3.4.9`.I have tried to set `watch flag` to 1, but that doesn't work. And I also tried to not call `zoo_aget_children` in callbak, but that doesn't work too.

## Result:

Keep printing

> callback called.
>   callback called.
>   callback called.
>   callback called.

## Question:

**WHY? Do I use zookeeper c api the wrong way?**

Comment: I have tried to set `watch flag` to 1, but that doesn't work. And I also tried to not call `zoo_aget_children` in `callbak`, but that doesn't work too.

Comment: Three things: Are you programming in C or C++? Those are different languages, and you should only use the tag of the language you actually program in. Secondly. please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to say if you're using Zookeeper correctly if you don't actually show us *how* you use it. Lastly please don't add crucial information in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I am editing it and working on the minimal example.

Comment: `zoo_awget_children()` works well, so I don't mention it.